# How to use Firebase Analytics Event. and How can we manage from Firebase Console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-analytics

I want to use Firebase Analytics to track my click events by users. In Firebase there are Functionality called Events. 
Use Code:

```
Analytics.logEvent("ToDo_Pressed", parameters:["User_id":"1"])
```

So, I am not understanding how it will track. And in Firebase console it is not updating in real time. Why?

Answer (score 0):

To reduce battery consumption Analytics most events are only reported periodically to the Firebase servers.

See the blog posts:

- ["How Long Does it Take for My Firebase Analytics Data to Show Up?"](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html)
- [Realtime Analytics For Everyone](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/realtime-analytics-for-everyone.html)

To see whether your analytics code is working correctly during development, [enable debug mode and use DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview).

If it crucial to the functioning of your app that the event be reported immediately, you can mark it as a conversion event. But keep in mind that this may impact the battery usage of your app, which hurts the user experience.